# inner product space generalizing to $n$ vectors $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\| y\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Problem: Prove that if V is an inner product space, then $$\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\| y\|$$ if and only if one of the vectors $x$ or $y$ is a nonnegative scalar multiple of the other. Generalize it to the case of $n$ vectors.

Proof: $$\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle +2\|x\|\cdot\|y\|+\langle y,y\rangle $$
then, using linearity of the inner product I get

$$ \langle x,x\rangle +\langle y,y\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle +2\|x\|\cdot\|y\|+\langle y,y\rangle $$

After all the cancellation,

$$ \mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle=\|x\|\cdot\|y|\ $$

By Cauchy Schwarz, we prove that equation is equal.

> Question is how am I supposed to generalize to $n$ vectors?

Comment: The first statement in your question isn't true. Counterexample: $x=-y\ne0$. The correct statement is that $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ if and only if one of $x$ or $y$ is a **nonnegative** scalar multiple of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if $\|x + y + x\| = \|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\|$, then
$$\|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\| = \|x + y + x\| \le \|x + y\| + \|z\| \le \|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\|.$$
From this, we can conclude that
$$\|x + y\| + \|z\| = \|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\| \implies \|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|.$$
Similarly, we can deduce $\|y + z\| = \|y\| + \|z\|$ and $\|x + z\| = \|x\| + \|z\|$. Thus, $x, y, z$ are each positive multiples of each other.

Now extend via induction.

Comment: Thanks, can you specify the method of approach? I don't really follow.

Comment: Which part are you not following?

Comment: begining of $$\|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\| = \|x + y + x\| \le \|x + y\| + \|z\| \le \|x\| + \|y\| + \|z\|.$$. How do you generalize to three vectors, by triangle inequality?

Comment: The first equality is by assumption. The middle inequality is applying the triangle inequality $\|a + b\| \le \|a\| + \|b\|$ with $a = x + y$ and $b = z$. The last inequality is applying triangle inequality again with $a = x$ and $b = y$. Because we get an inequality beginning and ending with the same expression, the inequalities have to be equal.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!